# How do I responsively wrap the unit marked with blur shadow in the CodePen?

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

The columns are made by page builder (wpBakery) and it's Wordpress.

Screenshot:

[image]

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/any_formless/pen/oNoJELy

This is my post layout.

In the CodePen,
I marked one unit with sharp shadow: that unit is real, it has its own container.
I marked the other unit with blur shadow, that's a virtual unit, it's not in its own container.
(Because it consists of elements from 2 different columns, and each column is populated by different queries, that's why I cannot put that unit in its own div.)

The layout should not change on desktop and on landscape tablet.

On portrait tablet:
Each blur shadow unit should wrap under the sharp shadow unit so that the sharp shadow unit is in horizontal layout, and take up the width of the sharp shadow unit.

On landscape mobile: should do the same as on portrait tablet.
On portrait mobile:
Each blur shadow unit should wrap under the sharp shadow unit so that the sharp shadow unit is in vertical layout.

Without media queries or breakpoints, only using Flexbox, CSS Grid or CSS columns (the responsive modules).

How do I detect when things don't fit on the screen or when the font is too small, and trigger the proper wrap desired without media queries or breakpoints?

How do I get the drop shadow units to wrap, even though its boxes are not in a div?

Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2vw;

}

.post {

  display: flex;
height: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: yellow;
padding: 1vw;


}

.column {
  height: 100vh;
  
}

.column-1 {
  background: tomato;
  width: calc(2 / 3 * 100vw);
 
}

.column-2 {
  background: darkseagreen;
  width: calc(1 / 6 * 100vw);
  
}

.column-3 {
  background: cornflowerblue;
width: calc(1 / 6 * 100vw);
  
}

.col-item {

background: grey;

  height: 20%;
  margin: 1vw;

  
}

.column-3 .col-item {
  
  height: calc(1 / 6 * 100vw - 2vw);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.column-2 .col-item {
  
  height: calc(2 / 6 * 100vw - 3vw);
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.column-1 .col-item {
  
  height: calc(2 / 6 * 100vw - 3vw);
  display: flex;
 gap: 1vw;
  padding: 1vw;
 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

.item {
  
  background: darkgrey;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-2 > div:nth-child(1), .column-3 > div:nth-child(1), .column-3 > div:nth-child(2)  {
    filter: drop-shadow(0.3vw 0.4vw 0.6vw black);
}
  
.column-1 > div:nth-child(1) {
  
 box-shadow: 0.4vw 0.4vw; 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="column, column-1">
    <div class="col-item">
      <div class="col1-item-photo, item">IMAGE</div>
      <div class="col1-item-text, item">TEXT BLOCK</div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-item">
      <div class="col1-item-photo, item">IMAGE</div>
      <div class="col1-item-text, item">TEXT BLOCK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-item">
      <div class="col1-item-photo, item">IMAGE</div>
      <div class="col1-item-text, item">TEXT BLOCK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column, column-2">
    <div class="col-item">AD</div>
    <div class="col-item">AD</div>
    <div class="col-item">AD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column, column-3">
    <div class="col-item">RELATED POST</div>
    <div class="col-item">RELATED POST</div>
    <div class="col-item">RELATED POST</div>
      <div class="col-item">RELATED POST</div>
    <div class="col-item">RELATED POST</div>
    <div class="col-item">RELATED POST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some basic code which shows the layout to give us something to work with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, this "It's impossible for me to put the group of elements marked with red in their own container, because all those elements are organized in grid columns." does not make sense to me. Why is it impossible to put a container around them? This is why we must see an example of your HTML structure.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth, I made a CodePen and I updated the post.

Comment: I cannot put the elements in the unit marked with drop shadow in a div because some of them are in my green column,  and others in my blue column, because they are output by separate queries.

Comment: I still can't see why whatever script you are using can't group things together since you seem to know there are, say, 2 that go in a certain column that are related to stuff at the beginning of their row. Perhaps you could show us the relevant bit of your script?

Comment: My ads column items are injected by url parameters and sorted by "weights", and my related posts are specified manually by ID. So there is no unique script that manages the unit of items that I want to reflow - the ones marked with blur shadow.